# Combine small lists into big list in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, extend

A basic question but i could not get the right way to do it.

I generate 4 small list in a for loop

```
emptylist=[]
for #some condition
  a=[1,2]
  b=[3,4]
  c=[7,8]
  d=[31,1]


  y=np.stack(a,b,c,d)
  emptylist.extend(y)
```

Then I generate next 4 small list which I want to add to x consecutively

I want a single list as

```
emptylist=[(1,2),(3,4),(7,8),(31,1),......]
```

I want to extend the list 'emptylist' by adding more smaller lists this way

I do not get a list as above but a list like

`emptylist=[array([1,2]),array([3,4])....]`

Any suggestion on where I am wrong and how to approach it

Comment: Remove the `np.stack` and just do `y = [a,b,c,d]`.

Comment: If you need tuples you can map it: `map(tuple,[a,b,c,d])`

Comment: Thanks, i overthought the problem,

Answer (score 1):

In order to get list of lists, simply add item in the list as:

```
>>> a=[1,2]
>>> b=[3,4]
>>> c=[7,8]
>>> [a, b, c]  # adding list a, b, c within list
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [7, 8]]
```

In case you specific to make the nested structure as `tuple` instead of `list`, you may use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) in order to explicitly type-cast it to tuple as:

```
>>> list(map(tuple, [a, b, c]))
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (7, 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `my_new_list = list((a,b,c,d))`.
It's useful for fast understanding and finding in a huge code. Opposite to `[a,b,c]` that could be read as `(a,b,c)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should just convert your internal lists into tuples, by using a very simple line. Suppose we have any list `l`:

```
l = [2,3,4,5]

tuple(l)       /*  The required statement*  /
```

The output will be: `(2,3,4,5)`

By using this you can easily resolve your problem by converting each internal lists into tuples.